# Accessing SQL datatype properties through linq

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, data-binding

In my sql database I have a numeric(3,2) field that I want to bind to a textbox. When Linq to SQL brings in the field, it converts the field to a decimal on its linq object. Is it possible to access numeric precision and scale so I can use them in validation or binding in the case of a custom control? Eventually I would like to prevent the user from entering in more than two decimal points on the UI Side.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2008/03/30/120875.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found you can do something like this

```
        string val = String.Empty;

        Type t = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo prop = t.GetProperty(fieldName);
        object[] info = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), true);

        if (info.Length == 1)
        {
            ColumnAttribute ca = (ColumnAttribute)info[0];
            string attr = ca.DbType
                            //... parse attr to get the info you want
        }

        return val;
```

It is not ideal because you have to parse out a string to get what I'm looking for. But it works.